# How to highlight all instances of a variable in TextMate?

Tags: ruby, textmate

If you place the cursor on a variable in NetBeans (at least in Ruby code) it highlights all instances of that variable. This is a feature I like very much.

Does TextMate or some bundle have a similar feature?

Comment: Added the tag 'ruby'. Since a lot of Ruby/Rails developers are using TextMate this might increase the chance someone might know an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I found was the mention of TMTOOLS - maybe it's worth trying out.

http://www.nabble.com/highlight-all-instances-under-cursor-td15231830.html

http://email.eva.mpg.de/~bibiko/downloads/textmate/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the TMTOOLS tip. Looks like this would do what I'm looking for. However the big fat warning message at their site lets me hesitate. I think this is too much of a hack for my taste.

Comment: For what it's worth I use textmate and gedit for Rails dev. I actually prefer gedit - it does highlight all instances of the search term.